# Codeigniter : confirmation message Javascript not show

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i was trying to show confirmation message using `bootbox`. i have download and attach the JS in my header page

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootbox.min.js') ?>" rel="javascript">
```

then, i have added the following code on controller

```
function index()
{
//This method will have the credentials validation
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">', '</div>');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
  //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
    $this->load->view('header.php');
    $this->load->view('login/content.php');
    $this->load->view('footer.php');
}
else
{
  //Go to private area
  echo "<script language=\"bootbox.min.js\">.bootbox.alert(\"Login Sukses !\");</script>";
  redirect('home', 'refresh');
}
```

}
and here's my autoload config

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','javascript');
```

but still the message box is not showing.

is there anything else that i should check ? 
or is there anything wrong in my code ?

update :
i have corrected the header page into

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootbox.min.js') ?>" rel="javascript">
```

Comment: Is this a public URL we can visit to troubleshoot?

Comment: @RyanKempt nope, i am running on localhost using wamp now :(

Comment: if the validation false it goes to the else condition.. and call redirect, try remove the redirect and see what happens

Comment: @OliSoproniB. it redirect to a blank white page without showing any confirmation message :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the redirect page add this to be part of the html code
so when it loads up it will show the popup

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        return alert("ERRROR");
    }

</script>
```

and in the else condition

```
redirect('home', 'refresh');
```

Comment: okay, now that worked ! but i want to show the error using `bootbox` like the following url http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: it can.. just include the javascript file for bootbox.js and use the library

Comment: @Cignitor please add the checklist for your best answer.

Comment: @OliSoproniB.can you show me how's the code ? and where's to put that code ? on a controller or view ?

Comment: add it in the view. read on the documentation of the bootboxjs.com
i think the answer is already there